# c++: Comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Tags: c++

I know I'm new here and I have contributed nothing to this community. 
Wine with a question like the first. 
I am beginner in c ++.

I have a problem when compiling a source ... this is exactly the error message:

```
In static member function 'static BYTE CBeltInventoryHelper::GetBeltGradeByRefineLevel(int)':
```

HERE IS THE COMPLET FILE.CPP

I put it on pastebin because I see some things like code

http://pastebin.com/UAAbm4yU

Comment: An `unsigned int` literal looks like `1u`.

Comment: To help the community, ask a clear and concise question :) Most of the code you posted is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the WARNING is here

```
if (level >= _countof(beltGradeByLevelTable))
```

You could make level

```
(unsigned int legel)
```

or do

```
if (static_cast<unsigned int>(level) >= _countof(beltGradeByLevelTable))
```

or ignore or disable the warning.

Comment: This would fall into the problem that the warning is warning about: if `level` is negative then the test should fail. It'd be better to cast the `_countof` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks  user3344003 , its worked.